# odd taxonomy of English

Tags: taxonomy, concept

The taxonomy of ox, like cow, bull, calf, steer, bullock, cattle, etc. 
is all odd to me, using different words for the same animal. (The same can be said to sheep.)
I'm looking for similar odd-looking taxonomy in English, which is even unscientific. 
Any example? (other than "sheep")

Comment: Cows and oxen were probably very important for spearkers of the English language. Similarly, Arabic has dozens of words for camels.

Comment: Just look around you. Mainframe, mini, desktop, laptop, tablet, smartphone ... Semi, truck, pickup, sedan, station wagon, hatchback, motorcycle, scooter, bicycle ...

Comment: [After the Norman invasion of England, the words in English for prepared foods took on their French equivalents](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/85638/2637). The Saxon serfs tended *cows, sheep*, and *pigs* in the fields, but served cooked *beef, mutton,* and *pork* to their Norman overlords.

Comment: @IlyaKogan You mean kine and oxen.

Comment: How is this "unscientific"? If anything the distinctions between the different types of the same animal are particularly precise (though perhaps varying by region - I don't know about cattle but I do know this is the case with swine - they tend to be precise within each region).

Answer (score 4):

That family of animal labels is not as odd as you seem to think. Those labels refer to different types of cattle, much like the labels man, woman, boy, girl connote different types of people.

- An ox is castrated male
- A steer is castrated male raised for beef
- A bull is uncastrated male
- A bullock is a young bull
- A cow, although commonly used to refer indiscriminately to the whole family, is female
- A calf is a young cow or bull
- Cattle is a general term for the whole family

Comment: Don't leave out the heifer, a young female cow! :-)

Comment: Don’t leave out the forgotten kine: they get testy and kick over milk buckets and burn down cities when you don’t pay enough attention to them.

Comment: Far be it from me to insult by omission cattle of any kind - I was merely explaining the labels the OP listed. My sincere apologies for any hurt bovine feelings...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but I'm not asking any justification of the oddness of the English words. Every language has similar odd taxonomy (besides the explanation you give here can be found in any dictionary). I'm just asking other examples in English.