# Eat a roast chicken but not a roast cow?

Tags: grammar, nouns

Why in English do you normally say I'll eat a roast chicken, but not I'll eat a roast cow or roast pig? Is it the cut of meat that determines the noun, or just an another English idiosyncrasy?

Comment: What makes you think this is "normally" said? Some context would help.

Comment: Actually you have a pig roast: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_roast and roast-beef.

Comment: Well, you don't normally eat an entire cow in one sitting.

Comment: I have seen many a whole roast pig at various pig roasts, barbecues, and other similar events. A roast pig will feed a lot of people (up to a few hundred, depending on the size of the pig/hog and how it's being served), each of whom has a portion of roast pork. I imagine a roast cow would be the same, except individuals would be eating roast beef (or barbecued beef) and it would probably feed even more people.

Comment: Roast pig is mostly used for an entire pig, cooked on a spit and is called a "pig roast".  Otherwise, you'll say "roast pork".

Comment: @Kristina Lopez After the Norman invasion of England in 1066, the French-speaking Normans were overlords of the Saxons. Lots of things in English have one name of French origin and one of Saxon/Germanic origin. These couplets are particularly prevalent with animals and their meat. The interesting thing is that English retains the Saxon names for the animals - pig,bullock, sheep etc - since it was the Saxon peasantry who tended the animals. However by the time the meat reached high table it had acquired French names - beef, mutton, pork etc. presumably to satisfy the Norman lordly consumers.

Comment: @KristinaLopez that looks like an answer to me :)

Comment: The name of the meat from a chicken is _chicken_. The name of the meat from a cow is _beef_. So one eats _roast chicken_ from a chicken and _roast beef_ from a cow.

Comment: Thanks Ghoul Fool but my comment is not fully "fleshed" out as an answer should be.  @WS2's comment is much "meatier" as an answer, IMO. :-)

Comment: @JohnLawler  Most beef that is worth eating comes from a castrated male "bullock", perhaps "steer" in American parlance. Though old milking cows do get ground up for hamburgers.

Comment: Likewise, most chicken comes from female chickens. Doesn't matter unless you're eating organ meat.

Comment: Of possibly related interest: *[Normans vs. Saxons: cow = beef, sheep = mutton, chicken =?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85638)*

Comment: @JohnLawler I was the son of a butcher. And I can tell you that cow-beef is not what you supply to your best customers.

Comment: But the question is about grammar, not cooking. The term is _roast beef,_ whatever its provenance -- unless it's roast veal from a calf, of course.

Comment: @JohnLawler And according to [this article](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/food-and-drink/features/forget-wagyu-old-british-dairy-cows-make-best-beef/) cow beef, for roasting, is making a comeback in London restaurants, thanks to the Spanish. My late father is undoubtedly turning in his grave.

Answer (score 2):

> Why in English do you normally say I'll eat a roast chicken, but not I'll eat a roast cow or roast pig?

That's because you're confusing the animal for its meat in this kind of utterance.

The meat of a chicken is normally referred to as only *chicken*. However, the meat of a cow/bull/steer/bullock/etc. is referred to as *beef*. If the bovine is a calf, the term *veal* might be used instead. The meat of a pig is referred to as *pork*. Likewise, a lamb (baby sheep)'s meat would be *lamb*, but adult sheep would probably be *mutton* instead. In the US it's common to call adult sheep's meat *lamb* as well.

So, when constructing a sentence about roast meats, it's common to see *roast chicken*, *roast beef*, *roast veal*, *roast pork*, *roast lamb*, *roast mutton*, etc. As you're referring to the meat and not the animal, it would be incorrect to mention the animal as a whole.

Comment: Grilled fish anyone? Roast lamb? Rabbit stew? Turkey breast... these names also refer to the animals when they are alive.

Comment: In the U.S., it's not common to eat adult sheep's meat at all, but I don't often hear mutton referred to as *lamb*. Something I do hear is *chevon* referred to as *mutton*, however.