# The collective noun 'duck'

Tags: indefinite-articles, collective-nouns

I know that collective nouns don't take the indefinite article as the one in the following construction:

- They had 'duck' for lunch.

But is it Ok if we use it In the same construction, especially, to emphasize that they had only one duck?

- They had 'a duck'  for lunch.

Comment: Yeah, that's totally fine.  But this question would find a better home on our sister site, [ELL.se].  Also, I'm not great on terminology, but I believe "duck" in the first instance isn't a "collective noun", but a "mass noun". The collective noun associated with ducks is "a flock", IIUC.

Comment: The contrast is between the non-count noun "duck", which denotes a food substance, and the count use where "a duck" denotes a particular kind of waterbird.

Comment: @DanBorn: Yea it seems that l've used the wrong term. I should have used 'non-count noun or mass noun:. Anyway thanks for your comment.

Comment: @BillJ: l do agree with you. I was seeking confirmation about the correctness of  'duck'  as a count noun in the second construction.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. You can use the definite article, the indefinite article, or no article at all. All three versions have meaning. So, it's not clear what you're asking. As far as I can tell, the answer is simply "yes, it's okay."

Answer (score 4):

I think I've answered this question [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/430783/eat-a-roast-chicken-but-not-a-roast-cow/430840#430840) before, but I'll apply the answer here.

What happens is that the noun *duck* is not referring to the specific animal nor to the type of animal, but rather to the meat of the animal. The meat of a duck is also called *duck*. The meat of a chicken, as a parallel, is also called *chicken*.

However, the name of the meat does not always share the name with the name of the animal. Contrast this with the meat of a cow or steer which is called *beef* or the meat of a pig which can be called *pork*.

This being said, be aware of the difference in phrasing:

> **They had *duck* for dinner.**
> Refers to the kind of meat that was eaten.
>
> **They had *a duck* for dinner.**
> Refers to the quantity of the animal that was eaten

Comment: Your answer is really simple and clear. Thank you very much.